# Helix around helix parametric equation?

Tags: geometry, 3d, parametric

I know the parametric equation for a $3D$ helix is:

$x = R \cos t$

$y = R \sin t$

$z = h t$

Can somebody explain to me this parametric equation (image and equation from Wolfram) for a "Helix around helix" / Slinky:

$x = [R + a \cos(\omega t)] \cos t$

$y = [R + a \cos(\omega t)] \sin t$

$z = h t + a \sin(\omega t)$.

[image: helix around helix]

I don't understand what are the variables '$a$' and '$\omega$' supposed to represent. I assume '$h$' is the height?

How could I expand those equations for an $n$-number of helices? (say this is $2$ helices, what would change in the formula for $3$ helices?)

I would like to be able to generate such structures in Solid Works. I can get the simple $3D$ helix from the equations, but if I try with the "Slinky" one it only makes strange (yet beautiful) shapes.

Any help? I know this is way over my head, but the coil-made of a coil-made of a coil structure has obsessed me for quite some time now (I would like to sculpt it in real-life, but first model it in $3D$)

Thanks!

Comment: $\omega $ oscilates rapidly and gives the slinky effect, a is the amplitude , reflected in a rather small radius for the coil of the slinky , R is the widest loop of the helix and h is the pitch of the larger helix. Thanks, fun to draw!

Comment: Could you explain what value should the Omega (w) have in the equation? It's not just a number, it has to be some kind of longer function (the oscillation, like a sinewave function or something?)? Sorry, my math terminology is lacking.

Comment: I got a nice result using: $ R = 3$ , $a = .4$ , $ h = .2$ , $\omega = 40$

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to plot this in GnuPlot!Thanks Alan!